# Trying to pick the coin with the highest bias toward heads after uneven numbers of trials of 2 coins

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions

I'm a stats noob and this isn't a homework question, but I'm just looking for a way to approach problems like this anyway - not an actual answer.

---

## Question:

Two random coins are selected from a bag of coins which have random biases. All possible biases are equally likely.

The first coin is flipped 5 times, and the second is flipped 10 times. Here's an example of what we might get:

- 5 flips, 5 heads
- 10 flips, 9 heads

Now, the question is: Which coin should we choose if we want to maximise the chance of picking the coin that is most biased toward heads?

---

## Attempt 1:

I think we should determine the probability distribution of the possible biases for each coin and determine which one's average/expected bias value is higher. I think these are the (relative?) probability distributions of each coin in the example I gave above:

[image: probability distribution of coin biases]

Solving the integral of the first for half the area gives a bias of ~0.89 and the second gives ~0.85. So I think we should choose the first coin (5 flips, 5 heads) if we want to maximise the chance of picking the coin that is most biased towards heads.

## Attempt 2:

Following @whuber's first comment, I see that solving the integral for the bias value at half the area will give us the median, and that's not correct. The median doesn't take into account the size of the bias values on either side of it - only how many there are.

To concretely show that the median isn't what we're looking for, here's an example of two bias distributions that have the same median bias (0.5):

[image: demonstration of median's incorrectness]

The latter has a *mean* bias that is higher than the first one, and this seems to be the metric that I want to use to rank the distributions. I think that I can get the mean by scaling/normalising the previous bias distributions so that they're actual probability distributions, then multiplying by the bias and integrating - basically summing all possible biases weighted by their relative probabilities. Keeping everything unsimplified for explicitness:

- First coin: $\int_0^1 6\,b\,b^5(1-b)^0 \,db \approx 0.857$
- Second coin: $\int_0^1 110\,b\,b^9(1-b)^1 \,db \approx 0.833$

So if those calculations are correct, the first coin is the one to choose.

Does the correctness of this answer depend on the loss function that we choose? I'm not well acquainted with loss/reward stuff, but if we said that the loss/reward is equal to the difference between the chosen coin's bias and the other one's bias (such that the score is positive if our chosen coin has a higher bias, and negative if lower), then does the above solution hold? It seems like it should. What if the loss/reward weren't proportional to the difference and instead the reward was +1 if we chose the higher-biased coin, and -1 if we chose the lower one? Would this make the above approach incorrect? Perhaps I need to do some more thinking and learning about this loss function stuff and ask a separate question if I get stumped.

Comment: +1.  Your calculation compares medians.  Why should that be related to the chance of picking the most-biased coin?  How would it be related?  Going more deeply into this: what is the penalty (*loss function*) for making the wrong choice?

Comment: Great tips! Thanks. I've added an "Attempt 2" section to my answer, could you take a look?